# Field jobLauncher in com.example.demo.config.BatchLaunche that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Field jobLauncher in com.example.demo.config.BatchLauncher required a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher' in your configuration.

```
@Component
public class BatchLauncher {
    
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;
    
    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    public BatchStatus run() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException,
            JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {
        JobParameters parameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);
        return jobExecution.getStatus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have "@EnableBatchProcessing"?

Comment: Welcome to SO,  i provided an answer please consider to accept it id it satisfy the requirement to improve the community otherwise feel free to add comment below it .

Comment: yes i have `@EnableBatchProcessing`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many ways to resolve it, all of them is to resolve the been detection of **JobLuncher** in Spring IOC container as exception says the IOC can not locate the bean for **JobLuncher** class to inject in the **BatchLuncher** class, simple using **@Autowired** is not enough at all actually you are telling the IOC the instance of **JobLuncher** class will be provided but at compile time he can not locate the instance to inject so you need to provide an instance of it.

- Add the `@Service` or `@Component`  annotation to the implementation of your JobLuncher.
- Inject the instance of JobLuncher class in some custom class annotated by @Config and annotate the method injector of JobLuncher by @Bean to scan by IOC .

```html
    @Configuration
    public class JobLuncherConfig {
        @Bean
        public JobLuncher jobLuncher() {
        //return an implementation or concrete class of JobLuncher class-interface
          return new JobLuncher(...);
        }
    }
```

Indeed there are many other ways as well, more over i recommend to have more depth look on Spring container and inversion of control, you may start from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring) .